domain coloring with residue theorem +winding numbers to determine the roots of complex functions
I would like to know what is the theorem behind the video "Winding numbers and complex colouring" by 3Blue1Brown (https://youtu.be/b7FxPsqfkOY?si=A7NKmM3ErhUp_TzW). Based on the comments, I think it is related to the Residue Theorem, but I did not find anything about the Residue Theorem that is related to winding numbers and domain colouring. They usually only present the Residue Theorem alone.
So is there a theorem that connects winding numbers + domain colouring + residue theorem together? Are there any papers/resources illustrating this idea?
Thank you very much for your time and response!

Have a look at the argument principle.
